# Qual a melhor forma de substituir um método especifico do Web Api para arquitetura MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, mvc

Qual seria a melhor forma para substituir o seguinte método `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest()` feito em WebForm para estrutura MVC?

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);


  <script type="text/javascript">
// Esta função será executada:
// - Ao finalizar o evento do botão
// - Após o applet chamar a função que finaliza a acao;
// Por causa do suporte ao AJAX adicionado.
function EndRequestHandler() {
    if (document.getElementById("chamarFuncao").value == "true") {
        funcao();
        document.getElementById("chamarFuncao").value = "false";
    }
}

// Função executado pela tag <body ... onload="load()">
function load() {
//esse é o trecho que estou tentando arrumar
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
}

// Quando clicar no botão da acão, irá limbar os campos.
function limparTextBoxLog() {
    document.getElementById("TextBox_toLog").value = "";
    document.getElementById("TextBox1_finaliza_toLog").value = "";
}


</script>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157483/asp-net-mvc-4-action-on-ajax-request

Comment: Amigo, oq vc quer fazer?Pegar todos as requisições ajax do seu sistema?

Comment: Esse método é de um exemplo de utilização de um applet que está webform, eu estou tentando passar para meu projeto que está em mvc e esse método está gerando um erro, creio que é pelo fato de ser especifico do webform, necessito saber qual é o metodo que pode substitui-lo, o applet está funcionando em partes e "creio" que seja esse método Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest() que não deixa ele redondo.

Comment: Troca as duas linhas que tem essa PageRequest.... por essa linha "$( document ).ajaxStop(EndRequestHandler);"

Comment: Conseguiu fazer?

Comment: sim, o erro sumiu e o applet funcionou, tanto com ajaxStop,ajaxSend,ajaxComplete deixaram o código sem erro e fizeram o metodo do applet funcionar, trazendo dados do cliente(client side).

Comment: Da um joinha entao na minha dica, so para me ajudar com 1 ponto.